# windows xp: change background color programatically (how to redraw Desktop after changing registry key?)

Tags: windows, winapi, customization, registry

How do I change the background/wallpaper color on Windows XP programatically? I'm changing the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors\Background (with regedit), but changing that key doesn't change the background color, although that key is changed when I change the color from the Display Properties window. Any idea why?

EDIT: ah if I change the key and reboot, the effect takes change. So how do I make it take change without rebooting?

Comment: Why do you want to change the colors by modifying the registry instead of using the documented API for changing the colors (SetSysColors)?

Comment: @Larry: cause i didnt know about the latter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to call the Windows API function [SetSysColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724940.aspx).

Comment: And `SystemParametersInfo` for the wallpaper.

Comment: Yes - although the way I read the question, he's only looking to change the color.

Comment: indeed, here is the pywin32 code to do it: `win32api.SetSysColors((win32con.COLOR_BACKGROUND,), ((b<<16) + (g<<8) + r,))`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it by changing the registry directly. You need to use the API function [SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the `SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER` flag, and also pass `SPIF_SENDCHANGE` as the last parameter to have the change broadcast to other applications (including the Window Manager).

BTW, changing the backgroupnd by editing the registry using RegEdit isn't "programatically".

Comment: He would have to use SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER first to get the current wallpaper, SetSysColors is much cleaner and faster.

Comment: it would be programatically once i wrote code to do it =). and that only changes the image, it doesn't work for changing a color w/ no wallpaper.

Comment: @Claudiu, you're right. I misread your question to be about the image instead of color.