# Set registry key for wallpaper solid color

Tags: vbscript, registry, wallpaper

The first part of the script does work (when the key exists - if not that's OK, that's why I have `On Error Resume Next`).

But the 2<sup>nd</sup> part is what I am concerned about.  It DOES NOT ERR, and I can see in Regedit that it did, indeed, set the Background to "0 0 0", but when I refresh the wallpaper, nothing has changed.

Oddly, if I manually change the wallpaper color, then refresh the screen in Regedit, I DO see the value change.

So everything is telling me this should be working, but it's not. The bold line is all I'm really concerned about.

---

```
Dim WSHShell
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

on error resume next 'it may not exist
WSHShell.RegDelete _
    "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\Wallpaper"

On Error GoTo 0

wshShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors\Background", "0 0 0","REG_SZ"
```

Comment: Are you sure other registry keys aren't involved? This key may indeed update when you change the background color, but maybe it's not the only key that does.

Comment: Settings like this are kept in memory. Use SystemParametersInfo
The SystemParametersInfo function retrieves or sets the value of one of the system-wide parameters. This function can also update the user profile while setting a parameter. 

BOOL SystemParametersInfo(
  UINT uiAction,  // system parameter to retrieve or set
  UINT uiParam,   // depends on action to be taken
  PVOID pvParam,  // depends on action to be taken
  UINT fWinIni    // user profile update option
);

Comment: It could be that the changes take effect only after re-login or restart.

Comment: BOND: I'm fairly sure, but it's been difficult for me to tell for sure.  However, see this response to Helen for a "pretty sure" level of proof:
HELEN: Yes, that's exactly what I found.  When I restarted, the change takes effect.  But, obviously, that's what I'd like to avoid by writing code to automate.  :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [windows xp: change background color programatically (how to redraw Desktop after changing registry key?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226466/windows-xp-change-background-color-programatically-how-to-redraw-desktop-after)