# Is there any way to read/modify the binary value of REG_SZ Registry Key using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, registry

Is there any way to read/modify the binary value of `REG_SZ` Registry Key using VBScript?

I just want to change the binary value of following `REG_SZ` Registry Key

```
HKCU\Control Panel\International\sPositiveSign
```

Note: I am asking for code to modify binary value (right click on key and select Modify Binary Value) and not the normal value of REG_SZ Binary Key. Please take a look at the screenshot in the below url:

**[Here I dont want to edit "Select" text of aDefaultSelect Registry Key but I just want to remove two trailing zeroes of aDefaultSelect Registry Key]**

**http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1614190953031**

Comment: Is there any code sample that you tried which did not work? This is not a "sho me teh codez" site ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "modify the binary value of a REG_SZ registry value"? `REG_SZ` values are by definition not binary. What is your expected result? What modification do you want to make?

Comment: @TheBlastOne - I tried googling this before posting here but I only come to know that it cannot be done, however, it can be done if the registry is of type REG_BINARY. But in my case, registry is of type REG_SZ and the code that would work on REG_BINARY type registry did not worked in my case also. Thats I posted it here hoping for some solution.

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiechers - when you right click on any registry, there are 2 options on the top. One is "Modify" and the other is "Modify Binary Value". Here, I am referring to latter one. Sorry for not being clear earlier. Please let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: I don't think the registry methods available in VBScript allow this kind of access. What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - there is a proprietary case that I want to automate by doing this activity. Isn't there any way or hack to achieve this using command prompt or vbscript or batch file or reg file (or anything) ?

Comment: >>there is a proprietary case that I want to automate by doing this activity<< you cannot be less clear about Ansgar´s question about what you want to achieve. He´s ansking for a reason.

Comment: @TheBlastOne - Actually, after changing this registry, the prop application behaves in a certain way that we need to validate. Does it answer the question more clearly?

Comment: You are aware that this is one and the same though? It is a different representation of the same data. Each change in the binary will also change the string. Maybe you can not type the character that will come into existence if you randomly change bits in the binary but in the script you can use Asc() on any letter in your string to get the ANSI code representation. You can then manipulate it just like you could the binary, by adding or subtracting numbers (you could even convert it further from DEC to HEX or BIN if it helps). With Chr() you build characters for your string again afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code from [Set registry key for wallpaper solid color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411495/set-registry-key-for-wallpaper-solid-color). Here, the (string) value set is `"0 0 0"` in the following statement:

```
wshShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors\Background", "0 0 0","REG_SZ"
```

Nothing stops you from passing any other valid string value to `RegWrite`, like in here:

```
wshShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors\Background", Chr(1),"REG_SZ"
```

If that is what you mean by "binary data", that´s how to do it.

Comment: This code doesn't work. It seems that you misunderstood the registry value that I would like to change. when you right click on any registry, there are 2 options on the top. One is "Modify" and the other is "Modify Binary Value". Here, I am referring to latter one.  Moreover, I have added the screenshot link in the question. Please take a look at the screenshot to get clear understanding of the question. Please let me know if it is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing to understand for this problem is that the "Binary Data" of this String is not some different data. It is a different representation of the same data. You see the bits directly (represented in Little Endian Hex form) instead of their interpretation as a Unicode String.

Each change in one format has an effect on the other format, you cannot just change a value in one.
So if you want to change the binary value, the easiest way is just to check what the new String representation looks like and input the new String. This will also change the binary data accordingly.

One thing to keep in mind here is that you have to use the [SetStringValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method of StdRegProv not the RegWrite method. 
The reason for this is that REG_SZ supports Unicode characters, and therefore each character takes up 16Bits in the Registry (i.e. Four digits in HEX representation). Most values on a western system are representable in ANSI, so for each character only two of those four digits are needed. This is the reason why there are two zeroes between every two digits in your example screenshot.

If you use RegWrite you can not write Unicode Strings so you can never write values to the positions where those zeroes are.
With SetStringValue you can write Unicode strings and therefore access all positions of the binary data.

Now if for some reason you would have to directly change values just based on their binary value, you could access them like this:

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv") 

strKeyPath = "Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\11.0\Selection" 


oReg.GetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, "aDefaultSelect", bKey

For i = 1 to Len(bKey)
  bString = bString & Hex(AscW(Mid(bKey,i,1))) & " "
Next

WScript.Echo bString
```

This gets you the exactly same values you see in the "Modify Binary Data" window.
The difference is that in the registry the format is Little Endian, so basically the order of each pair of numbers is exchanged. The second thing is that as I already noted if a number is smaller than four digits, it is still represented with four digits, so leading zeroes are added for the presentation in the registry.

Once you got this representation you can add to the binary data as you wish and then transform it back using a code like this:

```
<for each character in your new data>
  bString = bString & ChrW( <modified binary value of a single character>)
<next>    
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, "aDefaultSelect", bString
```

Now as for your wish to remove the "trailing zeroes". First you have to understand that due to the Little Endian concept depending on the string this might be actually the beginning of a character not its end. Second, each character is always 16Bit. You can not just remove some of the bits as they are just fillers to pad the characters. If you do not pay respect to those rules the outcome on the final string may be very different from what you expected.

I would therefore highly recommend that you manually do your changes (in the binary data window if you want) then look at what it does to the string, save the resulting string, and just write exactly that string back using SetStringValue.